# How to pass array or arraylist by intent which has unserializable data?

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, serializable, firebase-mlkit

What I want to do is passing DataModel array between Activity by Intent.

DataModel class has Bitmap object and FirebaseVisionLabel object. I found many sites to implement this.

Many people said that DataModel class should implements Serializable or Parceable interface to pass `DataModel[]` or `ArrayList<DataModel>`.

So I tried, but the real problem was FirebaseVisionLabel class cannot be serializable. Also, I cannot modify that class because it is firebase library.

How can I pass DataModel array by intent??

> Point
>
> 1. Want to pass array or arraylist of my own class by intent.
> 2. that class has unserializable object and I cannot modify.
> 3. how can I pass or deal with it?

Comment: declare your `ArrayList<DataModel>` as static and access and access it using class name

Answer (score 0):

Use Parceable. It works perfect

```
public class Test implements Parcelable
{
    FirebaseVisionLabel firebaseVisionLabel;
    String testString;

    protected Test(Parcel in) {
        testString = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Test> CREATOR = new Creator<Test>() {
        @Override
        public Test createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Test(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Test[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Test[size];
        }
    };

    public FirebaseVisionLabel getFirebaseVisionLabel() {
        return firebaseVisionLabel;
    }

    public void setFirebaseVisionLabel(FirebaseVisionLabel firebaseVisionLabel) {
        this.firebaseVisionLabel = firebaseVisionLabel;
    }

    public String getTestString() {
        return testString;
    }

    public void setTestString(String testString) {
        this.testString = testString;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(testString);
    }
}
```

After that for passing data through intent

```
   Test test = new Test();
    test.setTestString("test");
    test.setFirebaseVisionLabel(yourObject);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, BaseActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("key", test);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: SEE THIS ERROR `java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.google.firebase.ml.vision.label.FirebaseVisionLabel@d7a3ee5`

Comment: I think he asked without serialized or parcelable @Arsalan

Comment: no he said that parcelable and serialized not work for him

Comment: @baeharam another way to do this is to make Singleton class and set data on it's object and get data from that object on another activity.

Comment: You guys don't get a point!! My question is FirebaseVisionLabel object cannot be serialized. So, I cannot use Parceable interface, then how can I pass it? It is my question.

Comment: Arsalan, Oh okay my bad!!

Comment: @baeharam make singleton class to hold your firebasevisionlabel object

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to get ArrayList data without Serialized or Parcelable:

Consider,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, your_second_class.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("<your_name_here>", your_list_here);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in your second class use:

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
new_list = i.getStringArrayListExtra("<your_name_here>");
```

Hope it will work fine.

Comment: `putStringArrayListExtra` is for `ArrayList<String>`, my goal is to pass `ArrayList<DataModel>`... DataModel is my own class which has Object variable for firebasevisionlabel and bitmap

Answer (score 0):

You may use Application class, which can be used in all the screen, activities.

So store array in Application class and used anywhere in app.

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseVisionLabel doesn't have too many properties. You will need to serialize Label / Confidence /... (anything you care) yourself by creating your own VisionLabelParcelable class.

So far, there are not enough use cases to make ML Kit return a Parcelable FirebaseVisionLabel. Most apps should extract the info they are interested in and pass around if they want.